# I have made a class and that class has 100 static methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I want to ask that i made a class which has more than 100 static methods. But class is not static, so i want to ask that do all methods live in application memory whole time or not. Or it is bad programming. please suggest me.

Please solve my issue.

Comment: I think some additional information could help. But why do you have an object with 100 static methods? Cant you divide them in more specific objects? I'm not familiar with programming on iOS at all, but I presume that all methods are included in the application memory.

Comment: a classic [god object](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=god%20object&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FGod_object&ei=3i_WTtnsCIzqOebqsHA&usg=AFQjCNHtBCEgpveUhO3Pm8cF2GR0Y30ZHg&cad=rja)

Comment: Objective-C classes don't have static methods.  Do you mean class methods e.g. `+(void) foo`?

Comment: yes, Actually i want to write reusable code.Like i have a navigation based app and each screen have a left and right buttons. [Utility setLeftNavigationBarButtonWithTitle:@"IphoneApp" onTarget:self]; - where Utility is my class which contains setLeftNavigationBarButtonWithTitle as a class methods which takes two arguments one "buttontitle" you want to display on a navigation bar left button title and second one is the reference on which screen's navigation bar title will display. so to add in each screen left bar button i have to  call a single line.@JeremyP

Answer (score 1):

Does it have any `non-static` method also?

if No, `class` should be made `static`.

if yes, i'll say design can be improved.

And all methods are loaded into application memory as soon as class is first used. however only one copy of methods are kept in memory.

Comment: The keyword `static` has no meaning as far as Objective-C classes are concerned.

Comment: This class only contains all static methods. I am confused to create objects again and again to call methods in any other class methods if my methods are not static, i want to reduce the cost to create objects. create new objects in programming is very costly thing. to reduce that thing i made a class  which contain all static methods.i did not defined that class static or singleton class. Will it better to create singleton class then make all methods as static?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want these programs available in a reusable context, then write them as regular external C or C++ functions and add them to a library to use in other projects. Then reintroduce or wrap them as needed. I know - it's not a popular answer among objc devs, but at least it scales much better when you begin to have really complex codebases.

> But class is not static, so i want to ask that do all methods live in application memory whole time or not.

Yes, and these methods may not be stripped. When you use these in other projects, you pay for everything. With functions, they may be stripped and you only pay for what you actually use in the program. Specifically, the memory of a function or method exists in the binary and in the program's memory only once - instances do not clone methods, they are referenced and looked up using a dispatch table in the runtime (like a vtable). Each instance of the class only accesses its selectors via this table so method count does not make an instance larger. Memory in this case is rarely (if ever) a concern.

> Or it is bad programming. please suggest me.

This is very unusual, and an indication that something has gone wrong in the design.